# why are chinese characters becoming ascii in vi?

Tags: csv, vim, awk, utf-8, ascii

My CSV file's chinese characters turned into ascii characters when i ran an awk code on it. I know this because when i Vi my CSV file in vim:

i see this:

```
words,country,percent_sum,week
å<88><86>æ<9c><9f>,China,16.5,11/22/15
å<8f><91>è´§,China,31.36,11/22/15
```

The Chinese words are turned into ascii characters. the only thing i did was:

```
cat myfile.csv|awk -F, '{if(NF==4 && $4 != "12/13/15-12/19/15" ) print }' > tmp
```

which is weird because i didn't overwrite my CSV file and wrote to a tmp file instead.

However, when i cat the CSV file in the terminal it looks fine. 
Is this a vim setting that i need to change?

i already have in my vimrc this setting:

```
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
```

Comment: what's the output of `locale`?

Comment: can you report if you `vim myfile.csv` can Chinese words be displayed properly?

Comment: This Q may be more appropriate on the related site vi.stackexchange.com . Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Good luck

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with vim if the Chinese characters display normally in it.
`cat` uses terminal locale settings as Alastair suggested, please check your `locale` and pay attention to LANG & LC_ALL. Also you can try type Chinese in your terminal to see if it works correctly, then your `cat` or `awk` will work as expected.

Comment: OP's report is the opposite of your comment.